# Coding a basic school assignment example from Swift to Python and am having troubles with simplification

Tags: python, python-3.x

I learned coding from school. Took Python last semester, didn't mesh very well with it but I wanted to learn it. Taking Swift this semester and it makes sense, so I've been trying to use what I learned in Swift to make sense of Python. So far, this method has been helping me out a lot.

One Swift assignment I had was about making a simple program to score points in a darts game. It went as follows:

```
//Swift example
var myTotalScore = 501
var roundDartPoints = 0
var hisTotalScore = 501

roundDartPoints += 6
roundDartPoints += 8
roundDartPoints += 9
var hisDarts = 17+19+32

func resetRoundScore() {
    roundDartPoints = 0
    hisDarts = 0
}
func addAllToTotal() {
    myTotalScore -= roundDartPoints
    hisTotalScore -= hisDarts
}

addAllToTotal()

print("You don't seem to be any good at this. You're only at \(myTotalScore) points. I'm already at \(hisTotalScore).")

resetRoundScore()

roundDartPoints += 9
roundDartPoints += 8
roundDartPoints += 12
hisDarts = 43+29+18

addAllToTotal()

print("Ha! It's almost like you're this bad on purpose. You'll lose for sure now. You're at \(myTotalScore) points and I'm at \(hisTotalScore).")

resetRoundScore()

roundDartPoints += 60
roundDartPoints += 60
roundDartPoints += 60
hisDarts = 22+30+3

addAllToTotal()

print("Oh. I get it now: you were going easy on me. \(myTotalScore) to \(hisTotalScore). Good game!")
```

I attempted to do the same in Python but was unable to make a function for adding the score to the totals and resetting the dart counts. I used the def function. That doesn't work, because what's defined in that structure doesn't seem to be usable outside of it.

So, I replicated that assignment in Python 3, as best I knew how:

```
#python example
myTotalScore = 501
roundDartPoints = 0
hisTotalScore = 501

roundDartPoints += 6
roundDartPoints += 8
roundDartPoints += 9
hisDarts = 17+19+32

myTotalScore -= roundDartPoints
hisTotalScore -= hisDarts

print(f"You don't seem to be any good at this. You're only at {myTotalScore} points. I'm already at {hisTotalScore}.\n")

roundDartPoints = 0

roundDartPoints += 9
roundDartPoints += 8
roundDartPoints += 12
hisDarts = 43+29+18

myTotalScore -= roundDartPoints
hisTotalScore -= hisDarts

print(f"Ha! It's almost like you're this bad on purpose. You'll lose for sure now. You're at {myTotalScore} points and I'm at {hisTotalScore}.\n")

roundDartPoints = 0

roundDartPoints += 60
roundDartPoints += 60
roundDartPoints += 60
hisDarts = 22+30+3

myTotalScore -= roundDartPoints
hisTotalScore -= hisDarts

print(f"Oh. I get it now: you were going easy on me. {myTotalScore} to {hisTotalScore}. Good game!")
```

edit: I'm sorry, I just now realized I sent this too soon.

So my question is as follows: is there anything I can do to simplify that? If I could've defined the functions in Python and used them the same as I did in Swift, I would have no issues, but thanks to that I've had to repeat the same lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your python function has to either explicitly say it's using `global` variables, or `return` the value.

For example, with globals:

```
def resetRoundScore():
    global roundDartPoints, hisDarts
    roundDartPoints = 0
    hisDarts = 0

def addAllToTotal():
    global myTotalScore, hisTotalScore, roundDartPoints, hisDarts
    myTotalScore -= roundDartPoints
    hisTotalScore -= hisDarts
```

And for returning:

```
def tallyScore( my_points, his_points, my_score, his_score ):
    my_score -= my_points
    his_score -= his_points
    return my_score, his_score

...

myTotalScore, hisTotalScore = tallyScore( roundDartPoints, hisDarts, myTotalScore, hisTotalScore )
```